# Update user profile information page - React useState

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, state, mern

I am trying to make an update user page with previous information to be rendered inside the input fields. Console.log returns the correct value but its not showing up as the initial value inside of the useState.

Getting previous user bio

```
function EditProfile(props) {
    const user = useSelector(state => state.user);


    const [profile, setProfile] = useState([])
    const userId = props.match.params.userId

    const userVariable = {
        userId: userId
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post('/api/users/getProfile', userVariable)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    console.log(response.data)
                    setProfile(response.data.user)
                } else {
                    alert('Failed to get user info')
                }
            })
            
    }, [])
    console.log(profile.bio);
```

Heres what I am currently using to display the input field. (edited for brevity)

```
const [bio, setBio] = useState("");

const handleChangeBio = (event) => {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
    setBio(event.currentTarget.value);
}

return (
 <label>Bio</label>
   <TextArea
    id="bio"
    onChange={handleChangeBio}
    value={bio}
    />
)
```

Was trying to do this before but object was not showing up as the useState initial value

```
const [bio, setBio] = useState(User.bio);
```

Back-end - I know that $set overrides all information, so was trying to render the previous information inside of the input fields so it would not be overrided with blank values.

```
router.post('/edit', auth, (req, res)=> {
    console.log(req.body.education)

    User.updateMany(
        { _id: req.user._id },
          [ {$set: { bio: req.body.bio}}, 
            {$set: { industry: req.body.industry}},
            {$set: { jobTitle: req.body.jobTitle}},
          ], 
          (err)=>{
          if (err) return res.json({success: false, err});
          return res.status(200).send({
            success: true
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create some custom component and put User as props and you will see that you get data.

```
const [User, setUser] = useState([])
```

better to change to

```
const [user, setUser] = useState('')
```

You can get some issues because components starts with capital letter
And array as default value may error after first render

You can move it to separate component:

```
<Example user={user} />

const Example = (props) => {
const [bio, setBio] = useState(props.user.bio);

const handleChangeBio = (event) => {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
    setBio(event.currentTarget.value);
}

 return (
   <label>Bio</label>
    <TextArea
    id="bio"
    onChange={handleChangeBio}
    value={bio}
    />
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
```
<label>Bio</label>
   <TextArea
    id="bio"
    onChange={handleChangeBio}
    value={bio}
    />
```
This was actually part of the return, is there something different I would have to do to implement your solution?

Comment: Hi sir, try to move it to a separate component, When the props changes you will get a new value in the input.